# Variable argument lists in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have a code like this :

```
- (NSArray *)executeSqlWithParameters:(NSString *)sql, ...
{

    va_list argumentList;
    va_start(argumentList, sql);

    NSMutableArray *arguments = [NSMutableArray array];

    id argument;
    while(argument == va_arg(argumentList, id))
    {
        [arguments addObject:argument];
    }
    va_end(argumentList);

    NSLog(@"arguments %@",arguments); // here i have an empty array

    return [self executeSql:sql withParameters:arguments];

}
```

and i am calling this method like this :

```
NSArray *results = [self.dataBaseManager executeSqlWithParameters:@"SELECT * from InfoTable number = ?",[NSNumber numberWithInt:5], nil];
```

But in when i log the arguments array in the executeSqlWithParameters method it's emty.
What i am doing wrong? thanks

Comment: Check if @"SELECT * from InfoTable number = ?",[NSNumber numberWithInt:5] statement return anything.

Comment: Thanks, it helped me because a have forgotten the "where"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just have a small typo on this line:

```
while(argument == va_arg(argumentList, id))
```

What you want is:

```
while(argument = va_arg(argumentList, id))
```

Or equivalently, to avoid a compiler warning:

```
while ((argument = va_arg(argumentList, id)) != nil)
```

Comment: Worth noting that the compiler warning in question is the one that says “did you mean == here?”. In this case, the answer is “no, I did not”, and the solution is the code you have at the end.